# Bootstrap Mobile Menu Dropdown displays as Desktop version

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, octobercms

I'm using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/) with a [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) Menu.

When the browser is scaled down to Mobile, the Dropdown still displays as the Desktop bubble.

[image: desktop]

It should display like it does on their [website](https://octobercms.com/) where it stacks in rows.

[image: october mobile]

---

**JS Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Ldm1p63r/

I've narrowed the problem down to being the `open` class added/removed from `<li class="dropdown ">` by the javascript.

---

**HTML Menu**

```
<nav id="layout-nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-autohide" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown ">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      Blog <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-item">
                            <a href="#">Category 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item">
                            <a href="#">Category 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item">
                            <a href="#">Category 3</a>
                        </li>  
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

---

**CSS**

I'm applying OctoberCMS css theme for example to style the menu.

https://octobercms.com/themes/website/assets/css/theme.css

---

**JS**

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.js

Update: OctoberCMS may also be using these files https://github.com/rainlab/vanilla-theme/tree/master/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simply added the same css they have on their site, except that it seems in your fiddle there is the `show` class used instead of `open` as class selector.

[js fiddle solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ox3vfdtp/1/)

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

[image: rendered]

Comment: The further problem I found was the Bootstrap JS is supposed to toggle that class in the html, but was failing. It's because that HTML menu uses Bootstrap version `3.3.7` and I was using `4.1.1`. I also deleted the included Bootstrap files in the October `/vendor` directory and used one from `cdnjs` and it fixed the problem on the site.